# question about total variation (measure theory)

Tags: measure-theory

suppose $v$ is a signed measure on $(X,M)$ and $E\in M$

how do i go about showing that $|v|(E)=sup\{\sum_1^n |v(E_j)|: E_j\cap E_i=0 \forall i\neq j, \cup_1^n E_j=E\}$

sorry it took me awhile to fix the latex

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the [Hahn Decomposition Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem), which allows us to split $X$ into a positive and negative set for $\nu$.  That is, we may write $X=P\cup N$, $P\cap N=\emptyset$ where $P$ is a positive set for $\nu$ and $N$ is a negative set for $\nu$.

Comment: so $|v|(E)=v(E \cap P)-v(E \cap N)$, so we can let $E_1=E \cap P$ and $E_2=E \cap N$, clearly they are disjoint and union to $E$. Is this all I have to say?